# Неверное отображение в Constraint Layout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Изучаю Constraint Layout (макеты с ограничениями). Ввожу пример из книги, но выводится вообще неправильный результат. Подскажите в чем проблема? Значения Crime Title и Crime Date заполняются данными из RecyclerView. Но почему отображение макета у меня вообще кривое?

Вот макеты с ограничениями для View

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот отображаемый результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. А как должно быть? 2. Где и какие ограничения?

Comment: Должно быть как на первой картинке.

Comment: Я же стрелочки соединяю к краям. После этого виджеты должны закрепляться, разве нет?

Comment: Они и закреплены (скорее всего). Но в левых ячейках ничего нет. поэтому они шириной 0.

Comment: Макет вообще лучше показывать кодом, а не картинкой.

Comment: В левых виджетах выводится сегодняшняя дата, заголовок и порядковый номер ячейки.

Comment: Код не позволяет отправить сюда.

Comment: В отображаемом результате нет дат и заголовков.

Comment: Дело не в дате и не в заголовке. Они отображается через код Java в RecyclerView. Почему изображение наручников не выводится справа? В Constraint Layout если я закрепляю виджет, то она должна фиксироваться. Если изображение наручников убрать, то все выводится как надо. Я не могу понять, почему это изображение все портит?